# gradle: sharing variables among some of the nested subprojects

Tags: gradle

Consider the following project structure

```
Root
  |-build.gradle
  |-SubProj1
  |      |-SubProj1A
  |      |    |-build.gradle
  |      |-SubProj1B
  |      |    |-build.gradle
  |-SubProj2
        |-SubProj2A
        |    |-build.gradle
        |-SubProj2B
        |    |-build.gradle
```

All Subprojects have a dependency on `Somelib` but of different versions:

```
Subprojects under SubProj1 -- version 1.1  
Subprojects under SubProj2 -- version 2.2
```

So the question is how can I pass a variable `someVersion=1.1` to subprojects under SubProj1 and `someVersion=2.2` to those under SubProj2?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to declare version variables for subprojects `SubProj1` and `SubProj2` in the root `build.gradle` file. For example like this:

```
subprojects.findAll { subproject -> subproject.name.equals('SubProj1') }
        .each {subproject -> subproject.ext.libVersion = '1.1'}

subprojects.findAll { subproject -> subproject.name.equals('SubProj2') }
        .each {subproject -> subproject.ext.libVersion = '1.2'}
```

and then you can get it in subprojects at the same level as `SubProj1A` as follows:

```
project.parent.ext.libVersion
```

Comment: `subproject.ext` is not `project.parent.ext`, but `project.ext`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler no, because `subproject.ext` is an extension of the `SubProj1`, but a variable is used in the build script of the `SubProj1A` and other subprojects of `SubProj1`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler added some more info to the answer to make it more clear